# What does this line of code using pandas dataframes mean?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I understand what `.get() means`, it's used retrieve values of keys in a dict variable.

However, I am trying to completely understand the following code to the granular level:

```
df['image_ID'].map(image_location.get)
```

Where df is a DataFrame. And `image_location` is the directory of each image in the DataFrame.

I think I understand what is happening here, but please correct me if I am wrong:

`.get()` is obtaining the path to each image, and then linking it to the image_ID, so they can be on the same row of the DataFrame.

I don't understand though, what .map is doing? I'm not sure I understand this completely too.

Comment: based on what I see there is it takes the image_id series and for each item in the series it calls the function identified with image_location.get (passing in the image id to the function) and returns that as a series

Comment: maybe write it as normal function and then inside this function use `print()` to see what you get in variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It takes the image_id series and for each item in the series it calls the function identified with image_location.get (passing in the image id to the function) and returns that as a series

Comment: I see, so Image_location is a dict though, made up of keys which is basically the image name, and values which is the location of the file aka the directory on my computer of where it is located.

Now, how does .map() work in this situation? Could you elaborate on what you are referring to by series?

Comment: series is the column of data,  something that map can iterate over and apply the function to.   So in your case the get function is a function of the dict object that contains the keys (image id) and  values (file system directories).   for each item from the column 'Image_id' it takes an entry,  then does a image_location.get() with the id as the only argument and gets the location back.  the result of that line is a series (list) of file system locations for the images.  hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html#pandas.Series.map),

> Used for substituting each value in a Series with another value, that
> may be derived from a function, a dict or a Series.

Each value in the column will be replaced by the value returned by calling `image_location.get(value)`

This is equivalent to:

```
for i, value in enumerate(df['Image_ID']):
    df['Image_ID'][i] = image_location.get(value)
```

Comment: I don't understand this, can you elaborate what .map have to do with that? 

Again, I don't understand that definition, and would appreciate a detailed explanation. Sorry, I'm sort of new to coding.